# How to catch error from bluetooth socket and print custom message?

Tags: python, bluetooth

I have a question, I'm a beginner in python, and I have a bluetooth connection script which I would like to amend for catching the error (if an error occurs).

The script (it works):

```
sock=bluetooth.BluetoothSocket( bluetooth.RFCOMM )
sock.connect((bd_addr, port)) 
print('Succeed!')
sock.close()
```

How could I catch it? I get this if host is down:

```
bluetooth.btcommon.BluetoothError: [Errno 112] Host is down
```

and I would like to print only my own error msg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual way in Python would be to use `try`/`except` something like this:

```
sock = bluetooth.BluetoothSocket(bluetooth.RFCOMM)
try:
    sock.connect((bd_addr, port))
except bluetooth.btcommon.BluetoothError:
    print('Host is down')
else:
    print('Succeed!')
    sock.close()
```